# Enable free shipping only for coupon only

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

How do I configure the Magento2 can do below promotion?
Free shipping with coupon code:

`(order >= $50)`?

I did google some result, some ask to enable free shipping method and set min-order-amount `$50`. that's not work. Coz, I don't want to show free shipping as a shipping method selection.

Free shipping only apply to user after they input the coupon code.

Answer (score 2):

**create Cart Price Rules in Admin**

1. Go to MARKETING->Cart Price Rule
2. Click on Add New Rule

**Rule Information**

add Rule name, add Description, true on Active, Websites, choose specific Customer Groups which you want to add, in coupon choose Specific Coupon Option and add your coupon code for customers

**Condition**

add this condition in your admin

[image]

**Action**

add this action in your admin
[image]

apply this code on checkout payment page

[image]

hopefully, it will help you